# Bounded context and Entity framework migrations

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-migrations

There's one thing I could't handle in implementing Bounded context with Entity Framework :

Having the entities (even their properties) distributed in multiple contexts , I feel the need to centralize the whole model in a specific area, that would be responsible for managing migrations.

Am I on the right track ?
Am I missing an important piece of the implementation puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, I used multiple `DbContext` In my project too, I defined each mudule's `DbContext` In following format:

```
public class Module1Context : DbContext 
{ 
     public Moduled1Context() 
        : base("MyDatabase") //<=== I passed this ConnectionString parameter 
                             //     to all modules
     { 
     } 
     ...
}

public class Moduled2Context : DbContext 
{ 
     public Moduled2Context() 
        : base("MyDatabase") 
     { 
     } 
     ...
}
```

And then defined a main `DbContext` that contains all `DbSets` from all module's `DbContext`s and use it for managing `Migrations`:

```
public class AllModulesContext : DbContext 
{ 
     public AllModulesContext() 
        : base("MyDatabase") 

     { 
     } 
     //dbSets from all modules
     ...
}
```

Comment: Mmm this would lead to big pain when comes to keeping contexts in sync alltogether

Comment: @HichemSeeSharp: yeah in this way, you have to keep main context sync with others.

Comment: since no other alternatives, I mark this as an answer.